# Get warning : re-installation failed due to different application signatures when update version application

Tags: android, apk, digital-signature, code-signing

on my device installed my app from play store, but I Get warning : **re-installation failed due to different application signatures** when update new version application from eclipse. 
i want not clear data from old version, when new update.
how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the app from the device.

If you have the release version of your app on the device, and your debug version has the same package name, it must be signed by the same signing key. But your debug version will be signed by your debug signing key, and your release version will be signed with your production signing key, which are not the same.

Eventually, if you switch to using the new Gradle-based build system, you will be able to have the debug and release versions use different package names, which will allow them to be installed at the same time, even with different signing keys.

Until then, though, you can have either the app from the Play Store *or* your debug build from Eclipse installed, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your app from your device and then run it from Eclipse. This happens, because the debug certificate, that is used to deploy apk's to during development is different from your key, that you signed your released apk with.